# How to use Linux Network Namespaces for per processes routing?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, wireshark, iptables

I want to crawl webpages through browser and store network traffic per URL (not only HTTP but also udp, rtmp etc.) I came across this solution to use linux network namespace for per process routing. Following are the steps I followed, however unable to browse the webpage.

```
ip netns add test
```

create a pair of virtual network interfaces (veth-a and veth-b):

```
ip link add veth-a type veth peer name veth-b
```

change the active namespace of the veth-a interface:

```
ip link set veth-a netns test
```

configure the IP addresses of the virtual interfaces:

```
ip netns exec test ifconfig veth-a up 192.168.163.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

ifconfig veth-b up 192.168.163.254 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

configure the routing in the test namespace:

```
ip netns exec test route add default gw 192.168.163.254 dev veth-a

sudo bash -c ‘echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward’

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.163.0/24 -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Open Browser in the namepace and get following:

```
sudo ip netns exec test /usr/bin/firefox http://google.com
```

(firefox:15861): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-xE8M4KnMPn: Connection refused

(firefox:15861): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Could not connect: Connection refused

In wireshark: `sudo ip netns exec test wireshark`
I can see Only Outgoing DNS requests from 192.168.163 to 127.0.1.1.
Kindly let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: Are you able to ping externally? `sudo ip netns exec test ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @tomf Yup and thanks. It helps me sorting out what I was missing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it. I am able to ping 8.8.8.8. The problem was in DNS resolving.

Update DNS resolver.

put `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`.

Restart Network.

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Now `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like.

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Finally.

```
sudo ip netns exec test /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome2/ http://yahoo.com
```

Comment: additionally:    `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o veth-b -j ACCEPT`        
                       `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -i veth-b -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the host /etc/resolv.conf a cleaner way would be to create a network namespace specific resolv.conf in the following path /etc/netns/ . The "ip netns" utility will bind-mound any resolv.conf on this path to a /etc/resolv.conf in a mount namespace for the process launched with the new network namespace.